# Fila de Pedidos em c#

Tags: c#, console, fila

Sendo que já tenho esse código:

```
Queue<string> Fila = new Queue<string>(); //Declaração da Fila

string opcao = "1"; //Define opção como 1

while (opcao == "1") //Enquanto ele quiser inserir pedidos
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cliente:"); //escreve na tela a opção que está pedindo
    string cliente = Console.ReadLine(); //insere o que foi digitado pelo usuario na variavel correspondente

    Console.WriteLine("Produto:");
    string Produto = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Quantidade:");
    int Quantidade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    string Pedido = cliente + Produto + Quantidade; //pedido um é igual a tudo o que o usuário digitou


   int ItensFila = Fila.Count;
   if (ItensFila == -1)
   {
       Fila.Enqueue("Pedido");
   }
   else
   {
       Fila.Enqueue("Pedido" + ItensFila + 1);
   }
     //Adiciona o item à lista
    Console.WriteLine("Deseja inserir outro pedido? 1-SIM | 2-NÃO"); //escreve na tela as opçoes
    opcao = Console.ReadLine();
}
//Ordena a lista


//Imprime número de itens da lista
Console.WriteLine("Fila Atual" + Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine(Fila.Count + " pedidos");

        //exibe os pedidos
string casos = Console.ReadLine();
switch (casos)
{
    //caso1
    case "Pedido1":
        Console.WriteLine(Fila.Peek());
        break;
    //caso2
    case "Pedido2":
        Console.WriteLine(Fila.ElementAt(2));
        break;
}



while (true) { };
```

Como posso:

1. Armazenar os valores na variável `Pedido 1`;
2. Criar uma nova variável;
3. Recolher os valores digitados pelo usuário novamente porém agora armazenar em uma variável `pedido 2`;
4. Caso o usuário continue, armazenar em uma `Pedido 3`, em diante.

Comment: Qual o objetivo deste código?

Comment: essa foi minha tentativa de fazer isso, mas estou travado.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer um registrador de pedidos, que pede Cliente, Produto e quantidade. Na primeira vez que o usuário digitasse, registraria essas informações na variável Pedido1, na segunda Pedido2 em diante até a capacidade máxima de 5. Ao final, eu apenas gostaria de ter a opção de exibir o número de pedidos para o usuário:  "há x pedidos". E caso o usuário digitasse: Pedido 3 por exemplo, exibir o pedido correspondente, isso é, o conteúdo da variável que ele digitou.

Comment: Não acho que uma fila seja a estrutura adequada pra isso que você quer. No seu lugar, usaria dicionário com uma coleção indexada. Precisa ser necessariamente com fila?

Comment: Não. Como proceder dessa forma que está me dizendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É inadequado usar fila pro que você quer. No seu lugar, [usaria um dicionário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) ou uma [`KeyedCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx).

Primeiro é preciso definir corretamente uma estrutura de dados para o pedido. No seu código, ela praticamente não existe. Crie uma nova classe no seu projeto com o seguinte:

```
public class Pedido 
{
    public String Cliente { get; set; }
    public String Produto { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

Troque a fila por um dicionário de pedidos:

```
var dicionario = new Dictionary<String, Pedido>();
```

Crie um objeto de pedidos e defina as variáveis como você já estava fazendo:

```
var pedido = new Pedido();

Console.WriteLine("Cliente:"); //escreve na tela a opção que está pedindo
pedido.Cliente = Console.ReadLine(); //insere o que foi digitado pelo usuario na variavel correspondente

Console.WriteLine("Produto:");
pedido.Produto = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Quantidade:");
pedido.Quantidade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Insira o pedido no dicionário. Defina um índice (um nome para o pedido). Vou inventar um padrão de índice, por exemplo: "Pedido0", "Pedido1", "Pedido2"...

```
dicionario.Add("Pedido" + dicionario.Length.ToString(), pedido);
```

Agora o acesso fica simples. Exemplos:

```
//Imprime número de itens da lista
Console.WriteLine(dicionario.Count + " pedidos");

foreach (var chaveValor in dicionario) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pedido: " + chaveValor.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Cliente: " + chaveValor.Value.Cliente);
    Console.WriteLine("Produto: " + chaveValor.Value.Produto);
    Console.WriteLine("Quantidade: " + chaveValor.Key.Quantidade.ToString());
}
```

Para acessar diretamente um pedido:

```
var umPedidoQualquer = dicionario["Pedido0"];
```

Comment: Não deu certo, não sei se coloquei algo no lugar errado, mas deu um monte de erros aqui, estou usando o Visual Studio, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Harison Abra outra pergunta com os erros.

Answer (score 3):

Olá!
Já que você falou que não precisa ser necessariamente com fila, fiz com lista, vê se serve para você.

```
        List<string> Fila = new List<string>(); //Declaração da Fila

        string opcao = "1"; //Define opção como 1

        while (opcao == "1") //Enquanto ele quiser inserir pedidos
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente:"); //escreve na tela a opção que está pedindo
            string cliente = Console.ReadLine() + " "; //insere o que foi digitado pelo usuario na variavel correspondente

            Console.WriteLine("Produto:");
            string Produto = Console.ReadLine() + " ";

            Console.WriteLine("Quantidade:");
            int Quantidade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string Pedido = cliente + Produto + Quantidade; //pedido um é igual a tudo o que o usuário digitou



            //Adiciona o item à lista
            Fila.Add(Pedido);
            Console.WriteLine("Deseja inserir outro pedido? 1-SIM | 2-NÃO"); //escreve na tela as opçoes
            opcao = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //Ordena a lista

        Console.WriteLine(Fila.Count + " pedidos");


        //exibe os pedidos
        int a = 1;
        foreach (string pedido in Fila)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Pedido nº: "+ a +" "+ pedido);
            a++;
        }


        while (true) { };

    }
}
```

}